# Coding error when deploying with ant migration tool

Tags: deployment, ant, deployment-error, windows10

I am trying to deploy using the ANT Migration Tool to a test environment before pushing this file to the master branch. However, when running the "ant deploy" command I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Underlying stream encoding 'Cp1252' and input paramter for writeStartDocument() method 'UTF-8' do not match.
```

[image]

I tried to solve this using the following line:

```
ant deploy -Dfile.encoding = UTF-8
```

In this line I used all its variants (lowercase, uppercase, mixed, quotes, etc) but it didn't work either. Any idea how to fix it?

Note: I am using a W10 64 bits system

Comment: Hi @Alexis, have you verified that the package.xml is structured correctly and not missing any closing tags? Looking at that error there is a line about a premature end of line which can sometimes be caused by a malformed xml.

Comment: Hello @CallumMacErlich

Yes, I checked that. In fact, when I run from another OS (such as MacOS or Linux) it runs without problems. The detail is the Cp1252 or Windows1252 encoding that the windows operating system itself has. I even tried editing the file in a more basic editor like notepad++ or notepad and verifying that the format is UTF-8 but I couldn't even run it on a windows machine. The problem is that the machine where I have to work is Windows